# Could I connect USB wires to this mysterious device?

Tags: usb, identification, reverse-engineering

In a treasure box, as I call the boxes full of old computer electrical parts, I have found a device marked [HannStar MV-4 94v-0 0611 E89382](https://www.google.cz/search?q=hannstar%2094v-0%200611%20E89382&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=w3SjU-e-Cs6c_wb814CIAQ#channel=sb&q=hannstar%20MV-4%2094v-0%200611%20E89382&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbs=li:1). I'm intentionally linking you to google search so that you can see that it finds nothing at the moment.

[image: HannStar MV-4 94v-0 0611 E89382 - back view]
[image: HannStar MV-4 94v-0 0611 E89382 - front view]
<sup>The MAC address has been censored.</sup>

[image]

I can see promising USB pins on the PCB. This made me think the device can work via USB. However the number of colored wires exceeds that of USB - it was originally connected to mainboard of laptop.

The device has `MAC XXXXXXXXXXXX` on the other side. I believe it's a Bluetooth or Wi-Fi transmitter - that would be very useful for Raspberry Pi.

I have tried to [contact HannStarr](http://www.hannstar.com/Common.aspx?mid=93&tmid=93&modid=1) but their website really sucks and their contact form does not work beyond capability of Firebug (which I usually use to repair broken pages). This was my message meant to them (in case you can send it):

> Hello, I have somehow salvaged a nice piece of hardware made by Your
>   company.
>
> It might be a little old, but I'm very interested in using it (as an
>   engineer).
>
> Can I please ask you for any technical documentation you are allowed
>   to share about it? It's marked HannStar MV-4 94v-0 0611 E89382. Here
>   is an image of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvhOr.jpg.
>
> I will be very grateful,
>   ****** ***** - *******@*****.**
>
> PS: Making <input> field 300px high doesn't allow for multiple lines of text. Tell this your webmaster. He should, instead, use <textarea>

Comment: HannStar MV-4 looks to be a laptop model.  Any chance of a pic of the other side so we can see the chips?

Comment: You will see no chips unfortunately. Like many other transmitter boards it's all covered in metallic box. But it definitely comes from laptop. I will add the picture anyway.

Comment: P.S. the first 3 octets of the mac address are common to the manufacturer. The last 3 are the unique ones.

Comment: P.P.S. try censoring the barcode too next time ;)

Comment: What is barcode?

Comment: Tomáš, the barcode is the series of stripes on the label above the MAC address. It encodes the MAC address in an easily machine-readable form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a BT2.0 + EDR Slim Module similar to FCC ID MSQBT183 (Use the FCC OED ID Search for photos and some documentation). It has `Implement 802.11 coexistence solution by AFH (Adjacent Frequency Hopping), WCS (Wireless Coexistence System), and Bluetooth Priority`. The FCC documents show a similar board without the usb points labeled, but that's most likely just a revision difference. Your pictures show BT183 Rev 1.33. **So I'm 99% sure this is an Asus BT-183 module.**

Hannstar is a OEM manufacturer which builds products by OEM design, like Foxconn. As such, the product is probably under NDA and they will not provide any information.

The MAC label on one side is the Bluetooth Mac address, like a ethernet or wifi mac address, it's a pre-progammed globally unique hardware identifier number.

The extra wires are likely for the Bluetooth activity light, a bluetooth on/off switch, the 802.11 coexistence features and who knows what else.

That said, as long as you provide 3.3V for the VCC instead of 5V, and connect a usb cable to the appropriate test points labeled D+ and D-, it should be recognized by your computer, provided you have the drivers. Once it is recognized, find the USB VID/PID pair, and look for a driver based on that.

**Frankly, a 3 dollar ebay mini bluetooth adaptor is easier**

Comment: Easy things are not fun, you know? :) Anyway thanks a lot, you helped me more than I expected. I'm wondering if I can pair my laptop with itself...

Comment: @TomášZato slight update. Your pictures confirm it's the same (well, revision) as the fcc id.

Comment: Does 802.11 means the device is [cappable of WiFi connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)?

Comment: @TomášZato no, its just designed to work alongside 802.11b/g signals in the 2.4ghz range, to minimize interference on both sides. It is bluetooth only module.